# What is this php exec()'s string vs. variable result explanation?

Tags: php, linux, exec

Out of curiosity, what is going on here?

Either I'm really tired, or the only difference I can see is that 2nd exec uses a string, and the previous one uses a variable of the same string.

//code

```
    $command = "sudo /bin/mount /dev/sdd1 /a 2>&1";
    echo "[mountDev] command=$command\n";
    exec($command,$ouput,$ret_val);
    debugArr("mountDev",$output,$ret_val);

    $new_command="sudo /bin/mount /dev/sdd1 /a 2>&1";
    echo "[mountDev] comman2=$new_command\n";
    exec("sudo /bin/mount /dev/sdd1 /a 2>&1",$output,$ret_val); 
    // error handling
    debugArr("mountDe2",$output,$ret_val);
```

//output

```
[mountDev] device=/dev/sdd1
[mountDev] command=sudo /bin/mount /dev/sdd1 /a 2>&1
[mountDev] output=
[mountDev] retval=32
[mountDev] comman2=sudo /bin/mount /dev/sdd1 /a 2>&1
[mountDe2] output=Array
(
    [0] => mount: you must specify the filesystem type
)
[mountDe2] retval=32
```

Comment: Are these run one after the other?  I think `mount` would give an error (though, not necessarily that one) if you tried to mount an already mounted partition.

Comment: To fix the `you must specify the filesystem type` error,  you should add `-t <filetype>` after `mount`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I am trying to implement the error processing piece for when the user tries to mount a drive with no file system, which answers your first comment, because this mount command will not work at all as the 'test' disk does not have a filesystem

Comment: Ok, just figured I'd point that out :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is in `exec($command,$ouput,$ret_val);`.  You missed the `t` of `output`. :P

You do have 2 options,

1. Its better to use [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open) than `exec`. Because you dont have to add those `2>&1` to capture `stderr`.
2. Also you are using `sudo` in `exec`. That means if the user who is running your php file must be in `/etc/sudoers` file. Better to use a root privileged daemon that runs commands for you and give you the output. You need to implement interprocess communication.

Comment: AND if my aim is to make sure only one user can exec that command, then exec is the correct choice? My sudoers file is modified for this...

Comment: proc_open is cleaner than exec. From performance reason they are same.  But the daemon solution is better if you have many more commands to run. Its faster. Because apache doesn't have to allocate memory for them on each request. Its already in the memory from the beginning.